# Generic List .First not working LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
        var stuff = ctx.spReport();
        var StuffAssembled = new List<ReportCLS>();
        var val = new List<ReportCLS>();
        foreach (var item in stuff)
        {
            StuffAssembled.Add(new ReportCLS(item));

        }

        val.Add(StuffAssembled.First());
```

Keeps throwing

System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

what is going wrong ?

moreover how do i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you should add this to your `using` statements:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: That was it ... Intellisense wasnt suggesting I add it either. and I kept seeing (System.Data.Linq) and thought i was good.

Answer (score 6):

A few things to check:

- You're targeting .NET 3.5 or higher (or you're using LINQBridge)
- You have a reference to the System.Core assembly
- You have a using directive for `System.Linq`

Basically what the error message suggests...

EDIT: Additionally, your current code could be a lot simpler:

```
 var stuff = ctx.spReport();
 var stuffAssembled = stuff.Select(x => new ReportCLS(x)).ToList(); 
 var val = new List<ReportCLS> { stuffAssembled.First() };
```

Also, if you're *actually* using a `List<T>` then you might as well just use `list[0]` instead of `list.First()` :) Both will throw an exception if the list is empty, although the exception will differ, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This compile-time error usually occurs when you

- forgot to include imports for LINQ extensions (using System.Linq)
- forgot to reference assembly with LINQ extensions
- targeting 2.0 framework, which does not include LINQ by default